# Chain rule for partial derivates

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

It's given that  $P \equiv P(V,T)$ and $E \equiv E(V,T)$. These are known expressions.

If $S=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$, $\boldsymbol{P}=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}$ and $F(V,T)= E(V,T)- TS(V,T)$, what will be an expression for $S$ using chain rules of partial differentiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-S= \frac{\partial (E-TS)}{\partial T} =\frac{\partial E}{\partial T} -\frac{\partial(TS)}{\partial T}=\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial T}-\left[T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}+S\right]$$ using the usual [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule). Simplifying yields $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} = \frac 1T \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \\ S=\int \frac 1 T \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \ \partial T $$

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!